# Как восстановить SD карту после raspberry pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, микроконтроллеры

У меня полетела SD, выдаёт ошибку при подключении к Raspberry pi 3. Мне нужно её восстановить с помощью windows, чтобы  я её использовал ПРОСТО КАК НОСИТЕЛЬ.
Управление дисками пробовал -

1. Нажимаю удалить том...
2. Устройство не готово!

И так всегда!
Окей попробовал через diskpart выдаёт это -

3. DISKPART> clean

Программа DiskPart обнаружила ошибку: Устройство не готово.
Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале событий системы.

Comment: А ещё когда я подключаю CD у меня вообще windows не хочет открывать его как диск. Он очень долго его грузит. И только когда его туда сюда по дёргаешь, он как-то начинает читаться

Comment: для начала перестаньте путать CD и SD, это разные вещи. Далее `DiskPart обнаружила ошибку: Устройство не готово. ` - ну так значит нужно сделайте чтобы устройство было готово, скорее всего занято каким-то процессом, возможно проводник или чем там еще пробовали получить доступ к телу пациента. `Дополнительные сведения см. в журнале событий системы` я так понимаю в журнал вы принципиально не желаете заглядывать ?

Comment: В этом и дело, я не знаю команды которая выдаёт дополнительные сведения. Я в этом полный чайник... Всё что я пытался, это гуглить, но мне ничего не помогало

Comment: посмотрите [эту статью](https://zalinux.ru/?p=6819) где во всех позах разобрана данная тема. На крайняк используйте linux для восстановления.

Comment: я таких статей прочитал тысячи. У меня всё заканчивается на команде clean. Выдаёт ошибку  Устройство не готово.

Comment: если с виндой не получается то возьмите тогда какой нибудь популярный установочный образ linux, загрузитесь с него и вайпнете все сигнатуры разделов диска и файловой системы SD-карты, в той статье что привёл выше(один из способов) это можно сделаеть одной командой если знать какой диск нужен: `sudo wipefs --all /dev/ВАШ_SD_ДИСК`